# Particle system invisible - HDRP

Tags: unity-game-engine

**PROBLEM**

My particle effects are no longer visible. I'm unsure when, exactly, this happened. I recently converted my project to HDRP but I'm almost positive that it worked for a while after doing this, though I can't be 100% certain. I used the HDRP conversion Wizard, converted all materials and upgraded them to the latest version.

The particle system is instantiated where it should have been:

[image]

The system remains in my hierarchy until it is eventually destroyed by this code in Update:

```
private void                ManageDustEffects()
    {
        List<GameObject> dustToRemove = new List<GameObject>();

        // mark which particles should be removed
        foreach (GameObject effect in instantiatedDustList)
        {
            if (false == effect.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().IsAlive())
            {
                dustToRemove.Add(effect);
            }
        }

        // remove and destroy them
        foreach (GameObject effect in dustToRemove)
        {
            instantiatedDustList.Remove(effect);
            Destroy(effect);
        }
    }
```

**SETTINGS**

[image]

Material:

[image]

What could be causing this? Is it the shader? This guy here says the shader works in HDRP https://answers.unity.com/questions/1745971/using-shuriken-particles-with-hdrp-on.html and it's the one I used before HDRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody elsewhere provided me with these HDRP-specific particle shaders, which solved the problem:

https://file.io/ZozEUE1zac6p